# Use CSRF token on link

Tags: php, symfony, hyperlink, csrf, websecurity

I've a question about the usage of a CSRF token on a link. In my case, I want protect my delete links with a CSRF token. I've found how to do it:

In my template, I use **Twig**'s [csrf_token()](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#csrf-token) function:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger" value="Delete" href="{{ path('tube_delete', { 'id': tube.id, 'token': csrf_token('deleteTube-' ~ tube.id) }) }}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</a>
```

And in my controller, the [isCsrfTokenValid()](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/csrf.html#generating-and-checking-csrf-tokens-manually) method:

```php
if (!$this->isCsrfTokenValid('deleteTube-'.$tube->getId(), $request->get('token'))) {
    $this->addFlash('warning', 'The token is not valid !');
}
```

All of this work fine, but I've a general question about the CSRF token, as you can see, I use a different token for each delete link (eg: `deleteTube-1`, `deleteTube-2`, ...) with the object id in the token id. Then, in my session I've a lot of CSRF tokens created.

Is it the good method, or should I use the same token for all delete link for a class ? With a token id like: `deleteTube` for `Tube`, `deleteComment` for `Comment`, etc ? I think it's better to have a different token for each link, but maybe it's overhead ?

Comment: I think the Symfony's main csrf token used in forms, is only one per project. So why would be a bad idea for you to use only one per all links too?

Comment: For exemple if I go on my form Tube, on the add form I've always the same token (for the session), if I edit a tube, it's the same token than the add form, and the same for all edited tube. The same on my delete links who call a controller action in which I create a form with 2 button (Confirm delete, Cancel) to have a CSRF protection with the form and a confirmation. In this case, I've the same token for all my delete link who use this method, because symfony create a _csrf/form token in session and reuse it.

Comment: CSRF's (Cross-Site Request Forgery) purpose is to prevent a malicious web site to make action through users's authenticated session.IMHO it's completely enough to have one token for all of your links, because more tokens won't enhance security...

Comment: @HonzaRydrych: I'm ok with you, it's why I ask the question, because maybe one token is sufficient to protect the link. It's why I suggest one per object is maybe too much. I wait fot other answers :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can render JavaScript confirm box for every link. In Your controller:

```
private function createDeleteForm(Article $article)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('news_delete', array('id' => $article->getId())))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->add(
            'submit',
            'Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\SubmitType',
            ['label'=>'Delete', 'attr' => ['onclick'=>'return confirm("Are you sure?")', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger']]
        )
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSRF protection is to guarantee that a user voluntarily made an action.
You don't need to generate 1 token for each object as it is not the purpose of the CSRF protection to differentiate your objects, a single token per action is okay.

From [OWASP - CSRF](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/csrf):

> Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) is an attack that forces an end user to execute unwanted actions on a web application in which they’re currently authenticated.

---

About **Symfony**:
If you generate a single token for all your links, they have the same token value, it does not change at each `csrf_token()` call.
Also, depending on your app and its features, you need to also check user permissions to delete something, either by a [role](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles) (e.g. the user is an admin, he can delete all comments) or a [voter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) (e.g. the user can delete a comment if he is the author).